# Pulp can not execute glpsol.exe

Tags: python

I new to python. i was wring a transportation problem solving.when i called out Pulpi, it was caught error

```
from pulp import LpProblem, LpVariable, LpStatus, LpMinimize, GLPK, value

M = 3
N = 5
a = range(1,M+1)
a1 = range(M)
b = range(1,N+1)
b1 =  range(N)

xindx = [(a[i],b[j]) for j in b1 for i in a1]

model =  LpProblem("Transportation_LP_Problem",LpMinimize)

x = LpVariable.dicts("X",xindx,0,None)

model += 2190 * x[1,1] + 46650 * x[1,2] + 25110 * x[1,3] + 8040 * x[1,4] + 6720 * x[1,5] \
+ 1800*x[2,1] + 24600 * x[2,2] + 50610 * x[2,3] + 46200 * x[2,4] + 57780 * x[2,5] \
+ 1500*x[3,1] + 45960 * x[3,2] + 24420 * x[3,3] + 7350 * x[3,4] + 6030 * x[3,5],"Transportation_cost"

model += x[1,1] + x[1,2] + x[1,3] + x[1,4] + x[1,5] <= 300.0, "Supply_Pt_1"
model += x[2,1] + x[2,2] + x[2,3] + x[2,4] + x[2,5] <= 260.0, "Supply_Pt_2"
model += x[3,1] + x[3,2] + x[3,3] + x[3,4] + x[3,5] <= 258.0, "Supply_Pt_3"

model += x[1,1] + x[2,1] + x[3,1] >= 200.0, "Demand_Pt_1"
model += x[1,2] + x[2,2] + x[3,2] >= 100.0, "Demand_Pt_2"
model += x[1,3] + x[2,3] + x[3,3] >= 250.0, "Demand_Pt_3"
model += x[1,4] + x[2,4] + x[3,4] >= 185.0, "Demand_Pt_4"
model += x[1,5] + x[2,5] + x[3,5] >= 100.0, "Demand_Pt_5"

model.solve(GLPK())

print ("Status:",LpStatus[model.status])

for v in model.variables():
         print(v.name,"=",v.varValue)

print ("Objective Function", value(model.objective))
```

<model.solve(GLPK())> this is where the error came in

```
in actualSolve
    raise PulpSolverError("PuLP: cannot execute " + self.path)
pulp.apis.core.PulpSolverError: PuLP: cannot execute glpsol.exe
```

how can i install glpsol.exe or fix this

Answer (score 0):

Install the glpk-utils and try again.

https://winglpk.sourceforge.net/